# Would an inductor and a wire in parallel have an equivalent inductance of 0?

Tags: inductor, inductance

Since the equation is \$\frac{L_1L_2}{L_1+L_2}\$ and one of the wires has an inductance of zero , would the \$L_{eq} = 0\$?[image]

Comment: Sorry if this is extremely simple, but I'm just starting with inductors.

Comment: Remember, current wants to travel along the path of least impedance. The current will completely flow through the wire leaving you an equivalent circuit with the inductor removed.

Comment: Believe the math. And the intuition. In this order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. An ideal wire has an inductance of 0, so the formula gives you an equivalent inductance of 0.

In real life, this isn't true, because every current-carrying path must make a loop of some size.

Comment: I know you're new here - an upvote is the best way to say thanks (and accepting an answer, but you should wait to see if anyone provides a better one first) :-)

Comment: Oh okay, I'll make sure to do that next time, and I can't upvote because my reputation isn't high enough. I'll wait and see for any other answers, but I'll most likely accept yours.

Comment: One question about your answer. When you say it will create a loop, do you mean concentrically about the wire, or something else?

Comment: Something else. Current doesn't just go one way. In your circuit, the current coming into the top has to come from elsewhere, and the current leaving the bottom has to go somewhere. If you follow the path it takes (through the ground wires, through the power supply, etc) you'll end up looping back to where you started. That's the loop I'm talking about.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense. So since it is in a loop, it has an (albeit minimal) inductance.

Comment: @ZachGramstad He means that any real, non-zero length, wire will conduct a current which will form a loop (currents always flow in a loop), so any stretch of wire inserted in a circuit will have some amount of inductance just because of their physical length (among other parameters).

Comment: So basically, this is implied. (Except the other direction... Whoops!) ![Current Loop](http://imgur.com/7bHWrYw)

Answer (score 1):

If the frequency is high enough, the "wire" can behave like an open circuit. On the other hand, the inductor (at very high frequencies) will certainly behave like a capacitor and the roles are potentially reversed.

This is due to the length of the wire being at one half wavelength of the frequency applied. This can be understood from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-wave_impedance_transformer) wiki article entitled "Quarter-wave impedance transformer": -

[image]

[image]

The diagram above maps to the straight wire being half a wavelength long with a terminating short of zero length in the middle. Therefore Zin = infinite. It's a bit more complex than this due to the wiki transmission line being two conductors of a quarter wavelength each terminated in a short but if it's stretched out it (simplistically) does the same thing.